# Asp.net Menu XML does not read properly

Tags: asp.net

I am building my first asp.net app, I inserted the menu control (horizontal) and binded it to an XML file I made up. Unfortunately, when the page is rendered, the menu shows sub-items named as SubMenu, SubMenu, SubMenu and my text property isn't applied, also the links always points to #. I looked at other people's code online and I cannot spot the difference. Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OuterShell.master.cs" Inherits="OuterShell" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/style1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
    Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#7C6F57" 
    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
    <DynamicItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Text") %>
    </DynamicItemTemplate>
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
</asp:Menu>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/menu_h.xml" EnableCaching="False"></asp:XmlDataSource>

<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

XML Code:

```
<Main Text="Main Menu" url="~/Main.aspx"> 
<SubMenu Text="Start Configuring" url="~/Config1.aspx"></SubMenu>
<SubMenu Text="About Us" url="~/About.aspx"></SubMenu>
<SubMenu Text="Contact Us" url="~/Contact.aspx"></SubMenu>
</Main>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your databinding code from

```
<%# Eval("Text") %>
```

to

```
<%# XPath("@Text") %>
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: I get an error: XPath DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItem' must implement IXPathNavigable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After binding the Menu to an XML file, you have to go to:
Menu Properties->Data Bindings (Click collections)->Select the menu item which needs Data read, hit Add, then select the added item and and edit its properties like Text and URL to read the correct tags in the XML file. That's it, the data is now read perfectly.

Here is an explanation with pics:
http://shawpnendu.blogspot.ca/2010/04/how-to-bind-menu-control-with-xml-file.html

Cheers,
L